# Sending entry data to embedded template

Tags: expressionengine

I have a basic ecommerce site which has a products page, in which a full overview of the products is displayed, including thumbnails, brief description, etc. On the same page, and other pages on the site, there is a sidebar which lists the products by title only.

Since the sidebar is reused around the site I want to set this as an embedded template.

With this setup, must I retrieve all the products from the database twice; once in the main Products page, and again in the sidebar? Or is there any way to speed things up on the Products page by retrieving the entries once in the parent template and passing them to the embedded page?

For example:

**products parent template:**

```
<html>

  {exp:channel:entries channel='products'}
     // display full product info
  {/exp:channel:entries}

  {embed='includes/_products_sidbar' data={entries}} // ^ Can I pass all the data from the above loop to this embedded template?

</html>
```

**embed:**

```
{if data}
  // if we already have the data available then use it without having to get it all again from the database
{else:if}
  // if not then use another entries loop:
  {exp:channel:entries channel='products'}
     // display a list of products
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better of using a different approach. Have a look at layouts:
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/layouts.html
 or, if that's not possible, you can use stash https://github.com/croxton/Stash too.
oh yeah, you'll get better help on https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/